# Play the sound that an oscillation/vibration would make

Tags: windows, audio, physics

I have an oscillation: for each moment of time **t**, I have a set of **samples**.

I need to play the sound of this oscillation (output to speakers).

Cross-platform C++ (or Qt) solution is preferred, solution for Windows is also good.

And please help me improve the question, if you know how...

Comment: Sinusoidal? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave

Comment: I'm adding 2 or more sinusoidal oscillations, and this results in non-sinusoidal oscillations

Comment: It sounds like you have the sound in roughly pcm format (or you could get it there pretty easily) as long as there is a constant interval dt between your t's. Once it is in pcm format, then you convert to wav and can play it with a lot of libraries out there (portaudio for instance). You could have problems if the sampling rate (1/dt essentially) is not a nice number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is C++/Qt code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<QBuffer>
#include<QAudioFormat>
#include<QAudioOutput>
...
QAudioFormat format;
format.setChannels(1);
format.setFrequency(22050);
format.setSampleSize(16);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
QAudioOutput* output=new QAudioOutput(format);
QBuffer* buffer=new QBuffer();
QByteArray data;
for (int i=0;i<22050*2;i++)
{
    short value=(/*Volume:*/10000*sin(2*3.1415*/*Frequency:*/600*i/22050.0));
    data.append((char*)&value,2);
}
buffer->setData(data);
buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
buffer->seek(0);
output->start(buffer);
```

Quite dirty solution, and I think it has memory leaks... But it works!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using Qt; http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Playing%20a%20sound%20with%20QtMultimedia

It uses [QAudioOutput](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qaudiooutput.html) to achieve PCM audio playback.

Comment: This is actually Python Qt... I'll try to "translate" it to C++

Comment: Well, playing PCM audio I think is fairly common so it should still be easy to find C++ examples on Google. It sounds like you're more of a physics guy than a programmer though so Qt might be too heavy for your purposes. Look at Justin Peel's comment about just saving your data as .WAV, and playing with a simple API like `PlaySound`.